# Send Raw Email (with attachment) to Multiple Recipients

Tags: python, email, amazon-web-services, boto

I am currently using Python 2.7 and trying to send a raw email with an attachment (CSV to be exact) to multiple addresses with Boto SES. I can send a normal email with `send_email()`, but I keep getting an error when trying to send to multiple people via `send_raw_email()`.

This is the error that I get with a comma-separated string of recipients:

```
Error sending email: SESIllegalAddressError: 400 Illegal address
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://ses.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-12-01/">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>InvalidParameterValue</Code>
    <Message>Illegal address</Message>
  </Error>
  <RequestId>[the request ID]</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

That's from using this code:

```
to_emails = "me@example.com, them@example.com"

# create raw email
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['Subject'] = 'Email subject'
msg['From'] = 'me@example.com'
msg['To'] = to_emails

part = MIMEText('Attached is an important CSV')
msg.attach(part)

part = MIMEApplication(open(fname, 'rb').read())
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=fname)
msg.attach(part)
# end create raw email

conn = boto.ses.connect_to_region(
    '[my region]',
    aws_access_key_id=s3_access_key, 
    aws_secret_access_key=s3_secret_key
    )
conn.send_raw_email(msg.as_string(),
    source=msg['From'],
    destinations=msg['To']
    )
```

Also, here is the error I get from using an array of strings for recipients:

```
Error sending email: 'list' object has no attribute 'lstrip'
```

It works fine if I have just one recipient, so it just throws the error when I have an array of recipients and a comma-separated string of recipients. Anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: I'm having this same issue. Can you take a look at your code and tell me if you pass `to_emails` to destinations or `msg['To']`? What is the difference between what you have here (creating an array) vs declaring it that way initially?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended it getting it after looking at some docs and some more trial & error. It turns out that I just had to join the array of email strings for the `msg['To']`, and then I was able to pass in the email array for `destinations` parameter.

Here's what I did:

```
to_emails = "me@example.com, them@example.com"

COMMASPACE = ', '

# create raw email
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['Subject'] = 'Email subject'
msg['From'] = 'me@example.com'
msg['To'] = COMMASPACE.join(to_emails)  ## joined the array of email strings
# edit: didn't end up using this ^

part = MIMEText('Attached is an important CSV')
msg.attach(part)

part = MIMEApplication(open(fname, 'rb').read())
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=fname)
msg.attach(part)
# end create raw email

conn = boto.ses.connect_to_region(
    '[my region]',
    aws_access_key_id=s3_access_key, 
    aws_secret_access_key=s3_secret_key
    )
conn.send_raw_email(msg.as_string(),
    source=msg['From'],
    destinations=to_emails  ## passed in an array
    )
```

Comment: I'm having this same issue. Can you take a look at your code and tell me if you pass `to_emails` to destinations or `msg['To']`? What is the difference between what you have here (creating an array) vs declaring it that way initially?

Comment: Good catch. In my final code, I actually didn't even end up using `msg['To']`, so `to_emails` is just a string of emails separated by commas.

Comment: This didn't work for me and getting this error: Exception: An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the SendRawEmail operation: Illegal address

Answer (score 2):

I believe instead of a comma separated string with your recipients you have have to use a a list of strings.

```
Recipients = ['1@email.com', '2@email.com']

conn.send_raw_email(msg.as_string(),
source=msg['From'],
destinations= Recipients)
```

So something along those lines.

Source: http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/ses.html?highlight=send_raw_email#boto.ses.connection.SESConnection.send_raw_email

The official documentation says a list of strings or simply a string. This is why it works with only one recipient.

Second attempt::

```
to_emails = ['me@example.com', 'them@example.com']

# create raw email
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['Subject'] = 'Email subject'
msg['From'] = 'me@example.com'
msg['To'] = to_emails


conn.send_raw_email(msg.as_string(),
source=msg['From'],
destinations=msg['To'])
```

Am I right in assuming your code now looks like this? If not, try this.

Comment: I just tried that exact approach, and it gave me this error: `Error sending email: SESIllegalAddressError: 400 Illegal address
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://ses.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-12-01/">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>InvalidParameterValue</Code>
    <Message>Illegal address</Message>
  </Error>
  <RequestId>[the request ID]</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>`

Comment: This didn't work for me and getting this error: Exception: An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the SendRawEmail operation: Illegal address

Answer (score 1):

The solution is set a string separated by comma to the header and a list to destinations field.

Something like:

```
to_emails = ['me@example.com', 'them@example.com']

msg['To'] = ', '.join( to_emails  )
```

and

```
...
conn.send_raw_email(msg.as_string(),
source=msg['From'],
destinations=to_emails  ## passed in an array
)
```

Answer (score 0):

When sending without attachment just assigning list works. But in other case the below code helped..Thanks @Ezequiel Salas

```
to_emails = ['me@example.com', 'them@example.com']
```

or 
     to_emails = some_list

```
msg['To'] = ', '.join( to_emails  )
```