# Boto SES - send_raw_email() to multiple recipients

Tags: python, email, mime-types, boto, amazon-ses

I'm having big time problems with this issue-- another question on SO that didn't solve it is here: [Send Raw Email (with attachment) to Multiple Recipients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29127348/send-raw-email-with-attachment-to-multiple-recipients)

My code (that works) is simple:

```
def send_amazon_email_with_attachment(html, subject, now, pre):
    dummy = 'test@example.com'
    recipients = ['test1@exampl.ecom', 'test2@example.com', 'test3@example.com']
    connS3 = S3Connection('IDENTIFICATION','PASSWORD')
    b = connS3.get_bucket('BUCKET_NAME')
    key = b.get_key('FILE_NAME.pdf')
    temp = key.get_contents_as_string()

    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg['From'] = 'My Name <test@example.com>'        

    msg.preamble = 'Multipart message.\n'

    part1 = MIMEText(u"Attached is the report", 'plain')
    part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')

    msg.attach(part1)
    msg.attach(part2)

    part = MIMEApplication(temp) #read binary
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename='FILE_NAME.pdf')
    msg.attach(part)

    conn = boto.ses.connect_to_region('us-east-1', aws_access_key_id='AUTH_ID', aws_secret_access_key='AUTH_PW')
    for recipient in recipients:
        print recipient
        msg['To'] = recipient

        result = conn.send_raw_email(msg.as_string(), source=msg['From'], destinations=recipient)
```

but, there's a caveat... this is looping for each recipient. Any variation of this *does not work*. Passing a list to `msg['Bcc']` or `msg['BCC']` will return an error that the list can't be stripped (same exact error as the posted question). Passing a string separated by commas gives an Amazon SES issue saying 'Illegal Email' in the returned XML. Because I only get an error from Amazon in specific situations, I'm led to believe this is an error with the program before it hits their API call.

Any `MIMEMultipart` experts have some ideas?

Comment: I believe what you're asking should be possible, though I don't have time to put together a full example at the moment. Check out how the django-ses package [implements send_messages()](https://github.com/hmarr/django-ses/blob/master/django_ses/__init__.py#L157) which is able to quickly send messages to long lists of recipients. Edit: actually, maybe not -- I see that send_messages() there is in fact looping over the list of email_messages.

Comment: You can send to multiple recipients if you list the 'cc' and 'bcc' recipients with the 'to' recipient. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9974972/mails-not-being-sent-to-people-in-cc

Comment: "now" seem to have no use?

Answer (score 21):

Basically you need to specify the email recipients in 2 different places using 2 different formats.

```
def send_amazon_email_with_attachment(html, subject, now, pre):
    dummy = 'test@example.com'
    recipients = ['test1@exampl.ecom', 'test2@example.com', 'test3@example.com']
    connS3 = S3Connection('IDENTIFICATION','PASSWORD')
    b = connS3.get_bucket('BUCKET_NAME')
    key = b.get_key('FILE_NAME.pdf')
    temp = key.get_contents_as_string()

    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg['From'] = 'My Name <test@example.com>' 
    msg['To'] = ', '.join(recipients)


    msg.preamble = 'Multipart message.\n'

    part1 = MIMEText(u"Attached is the report", 'plain')
    part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')

    msg.attach(part1)
    msg.attach(part2)

    part = MIMEApplication(temp) #read binary
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename='FILE_NAME.pdf')
    msg.attach(part)

    conn = boto.ses.connect_to_region('us-east-1', aws_access_key_id='AUTH_ID', aws_secret_access_key='AUTH_PW')


    result = conn.send_raw_email(msg.as_string(), source=msg['From'], destinations=recipients)
```

Comment: This is redundant as well as confusing. Has anybody figured out why it is this way?

Comment: It's explained in the documentation: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ses.html#SES.Client.send_raw_email

Answer (score 0):

msg['To'] = ', '.join(recipients) isn't working for me (throws encoding error). Simply comment that line and your 'destinations' in "send_raw_email" should contain a list. That will work like a charm.